# Improve Socket performance

Tags: c#, sockets, networking

I have a TCP/IP socket and communicate to an external sensor device over it. The proprietary protocol that we use has a feature that the device can send a packet to the client at any time. This is called an "event" and is very much like a C# event.

I basically implemented it like this:

```
...
socket.ReceiveTimeout = ResolveTimeout(timeout);
while (...)
{
    var buffer = new byte[count];
    int readBytes = socket.Receive(buffer, 0, count, SocketFlags.None);
    ...
}
```

With this code, the application suffers bad performance. I measured it in a profiler and it tells me that Socket.Receive needs 45% wall time.

Is there any way how I can improve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's most likely because `Socket.Receive()` blocks until data is available.

Try asynchronous programming, using [`Socket.BeginReceive()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.beginreceive(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Or the awaitable [*`Socket.ReceiveAsync`*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receiveasync(v=vs.110).aspx) if you're on .NET 4.0 and above and can use `async-await`